# UITapGesture not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitapgesturerecognizer

Code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(OpenBrandUrlLinkMetod:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
FirstImgV.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[FirstImgV addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

and

```
-(void)OpenBrandUrlLinkMetod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"hello!!"); 
}
```

But OpenBrandUrlLinkMetod not called.

anybody can help me.

Comment: Have you tried adding the tap gesture to a very obvious view? Maybe your imageview has something in front of it (a mask maybe?) or isn't accessible for some reason? Could you try this in a blank view to make sure the code is fine? It look fine but I want to remove some possibilities :)

Comment: where you are adding FirstImgV in UIScrollView or UiTableView

Comment: I have add FirstImgV on UIView.

Comment: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  are you using this same method in more then 1 label or image or anything ?

Comment: @HariMohan Check My answer

Comment: Are you using a swipegesture recognizer or any other recognizer in the view controller

Comment: @HariMohan Did you find a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Set delegate for your `UITapGestureRecognizer`,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(OpenBrandUrlLinkMetod:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
singleTap.delegate = self;  // set delegate to self
_img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[_img addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Check whether the gesturerecognizer is calling to your `UIImageview` by the following code,

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([[touch.view class] isEqual:[UIImageView class]]) {
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Then use your TapGesture method to do your stuffs,

```
-(void)OpenBrandUrlLinkMetod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"hello!!");
}
```

Comment: Please mark the correct answer so that others can easily get use of it.

Answer (score 0):

`singleTap` might be garbage collected before any touch event happens.
To prevent this you have to retain it somewhere in your class:

```
@interface YourClass

/// Your gesture recognizer gets referenced/retained here:
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap;

@end
```

and then later: (maybe in viewDidLoad)

```
_singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(OpenBrandUrlLinkMetod:)];
_singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
_singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
FirstImgV.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[FirstImgV addGestureRecognizer: _singleTap];
```

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into my project its working completely, you can see code and viewcontroller into this [VIDEO](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zedbmuqsmynx5zn/Untitled.mov?dl=0).

I just add this delegate `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`

Just add this delegate and try it

Comment: Did it work or not? I also send you video with your specific code of tap gesture, if its not working then tell me

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some other gesture recogniser in the concerned view controller. In that case this code should get you going. Or try this code anyways, and set up the delegate.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```